# How do I retrieve the first alpha character string from withing a longer string using c#

Tags: c#, string, split

Below are two example strings there I am trying to retrieve a label name from, the first one is retrieved with the .split function, but the second throws an error as the punctuation is not in place, is there a way to select the first set of alpha character until a non alpha character appears? While also removing any non alpha character from the start?

```
secondSection = secondSection.Split('/', ',')[1];

string example 1
191100201000430<*/SIZENAME,String,5,TOUPPER/*>
string example 2
191100400050100Price
```

Comment: Do you mean `alpha nummerics` characters?

Comment: Have you searched for regular expressions? Should do what you want. Anyway I agree Tim, your question is unclear until now.

Comment: Sorry I put the stings in the incorrect order, I will have a look at regular expressions, in the edited version of the question I can retrieve the label name, I was hoping to be able to do the same with the second string somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way to select the first set of alpha character until a non
>   alpha character appears? While also removing any non alpha character
>   from the start?

One way, LINQ:

```
string allowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var alllowedChars = str.SkipWhile(c => !allowed.Contains(c)).TakeWhile(allowed.Contains);
string label = new string(alllowedChars.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will try this now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *regular expressions* and *match*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

// We want 1st non-empty sequence of alpha (a..z A..Z) characters
var result = Regex.Match(str, "[A-Za-z]+").Value;
```

With a help of regular expressions you can easily get all alpha names (if you want, saym to ignore `SIZENAME`, `String` and get `TOUPPER`), e.g.

```
string[] results = Regex
  .Matches(str, "[A-Za-z]+")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToArray();
```